# Moving mail to folder removes it from mail account

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail, alias

I have two aliases set up in my Gmail account and on my Mac Mail.app I set up a rule for each alias that if an email is "to 'Alias A'", move it to folder "Alias A Folder" - respectively for "Alias B".

The issue is that by creating this rule, it works perfectly on the Mail.app on my Mac and it sorts them well, but they are moved out of my Gmail account, so I cannot read those emails on my phone nor on the gmail.com interface.

I understand that I could just create a rule to "copy" the mails to "Alias X Folder", but then my personal Gmail account would get cluttered with mail from the aliases.

Is there any workaround or scenario for which I can organize my mails in a better way across my devices?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you created a local folder (On your Mac). If you create a folder in your Gmail account and point your rule to that folder. Every message will stay in your Gmail account.

[image: New Mailbox]

You can also make rules in the Gmail interface. Then those rules will be followed on the server. If your Mac is turned off it will also move those emails to the right folder.